# Why the fields of card payment are empty?

Tags: python, django, braintree-sandbox

I am creating an online shopping and the users should pay their orders by using a credit card payment. So, I created a sandbox account to test the Braintree API, install the Braintree and make the all configuration as it is shown the python files below. But, as you can notice in figure 3, the card information framework is displayed with only the card lables but there are the fields of the Card number, the Cvv and the expiration date of the card.

[image: Credit card payment]

Payment/views.py:

```
import braintree
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from orders.models import Order
def payment_process(request):
    order_id = request.session.get('order_id')
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # retrieve nonce
        nonce = request.POST.get('payment_method_nonce', None)
        # create and submit transaction
        result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
        'amount': '{:.2f}'.format(order.get_total_cost()),
        'payment_method_nonce': nonce,
        'options': {
        'submit_for_settlement': True
        }
        })
        if result.is_success:
            # mark the order as paid
            order.paid = True
            # store the unique transaction id
            order.braintree_id = result.transaction.id
            order.save()
            return redirect('payment:done')
        else:
            return redirect('payment:canceled')
    else:
        # generate token
        client_token = braintree.ClientToken.generate()
        return render(request,
                      'payment/process.html',
                     {'order': order,
                      'client_token': client_token})

def payment_done(request):
    return render(request, 'payment/done.html')

def payment_canceled(request):
    return render(request, 'payment/canceled.html')
```

After clicking on the Place order button, I was expecting to get a form like the one below but unfortunately, I've got a form without fields.
This is the template that displays the payment form and processes:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Pay by credit card{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Pay by credit card</h1>
<form action="." id="payment" method="post">
    <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
    <div id="card-number" class="field"></div>
    <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
    <div id="cvv" class="field"></div>
    <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
    <div id="expiration-date" class="field"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" value="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
<!-- Load the required client component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.29.0/js/client.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Load Hosted Fields component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.29.0/js/hostedfields.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('#payment');
    var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
    braintree.client.create({
    authorization: '{{ client_token }}'
    }, function (clientErr, clientInstance) {
    if (clientErr) {
        console.error(clientErr);
    return;
    }
    braintree.hostedFields.create({
        client: clientInstance,
        styles: {
            'input': {'font-size': '13px'},
            'input.invalid': {'color': 'red'},
            'input.valid': {'color': 'green'}
        },
        fields: {
            number: {selector: '#card-number'},
            cvv: {selector: '#cvv'},
            expirationDate: {selector: '#expiration-date'}
            }
    }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {
        if (hostedFieldsErr) {
        console.error(hostedFieldsErr);
        return;
    }
    submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
            if (tokenizeErr) {
                console.error(tokenizeErr);
                return;
        }
            // set nonce to send to the server
            document.getElementById('nonce').value = payload.nonce;
            // submit form
            document.getElementById('payment').submit();
            });
            }, false);
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Card expected form]

How can I get an "empty cart information" and not even have the cards fields while I have placed an order?
Thanks

Comment: @Reema Parakh, Could you please help with this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've provided _far_ too much code, and you haven't sufficiently narrowed the problem down yourself. Please provide a [mcve], with the emphasis on _minimal_.

Comment: @Chris, I have edited my question. Please check it again.

Comment: @Chris, could you please recheck now.?

Comment: @Reema Parakh, Please assis me